# ipvsadm: Access loadbalanced ip's from internal network

Tags: load-balancing

I have the following scenario:

```
ipvs-Loadbalancer - direct routing: 123.123.123.117
Realserver 1: eth0: 123.123.123.123 eth1: 10.10.0.1
Realserver 2: eth0: 123.123.123.124 eth1: 10.10.0.2
Random server on internal network: eth0: 10.10.0.44
```

Loadbalancing works perfect from from external ip's. If I connect to 123.123.123.117 I get a response from either 123.123.123.123 or 123.123.123.124.
If I try to connect from a random server within my network, it won't work though.

tcpdump tells me, that the request goes through the loadbalancer to the realserver but there's no response.
The setup did work on Debian Squeeze but since I switched to Ubuntu Trusty it doesn't.

route -n on the realserver tells me:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         123.123.123.113 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
10.10.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
123.123.123.112 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.240 U     0      0        0 eth1
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Try not to use the `route` command anymore, it's been deprecated for more than 10 years now. Use `ip route show`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem is that the kernel checks if the packet is routable through the interface which it came. If it isn't, the packet won't be accepted.

Disabling reverse path filter on the realservers did the trick:

```
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth1.rp_filter = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done from the local network. I've wasted time trying :)

The problem is that no source NAT is happening, so when client 123.123.123.99 connects to 123.123.123.117, it gets sent to either 123.123.123.123 or 123.123.123.124. Those systems see that the source IP is 123.123.123.99 and sends the response directly to 123.123.123.99. However the client there is not expecting any traffic from 123.123.123.123 or 123.123.123.124, and sends a TCP RESET. Meanwhile it's still waiting for a reponse from 123.123.123.117, which will never come.

Alternatively have the real servers (where ipvs is load-balancing to) on a private subnet, but you'd need a separate (V)LAN for that.